# Will there be a wrap-up blog post for Winter Bash 2017?

Tags: discussion, blog, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

Winter Bash 2017 ended a week ago, on Jan 2nd. Usually, there's a wrap-up blog post published 1 to 4 days after WB ends. ([2016](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/09/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/), [2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/01/06/winter-bash-2015-hats-off/), [2014](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/01/06/so-long-winter-bash-2014/), [2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/03/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/) & [2012](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/01/08/boxing-day/)).

Just to check, since WB ended 7 days ago, is the wrap-up blog post for Winter Bash 2017 still in the works?

Comment: It's live now: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/10/farewell-winter-bash-2017/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's live now: [Farewell Winter Bash 2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/10/farewell-winter-bash-2017/).

The reason for the delay was pointed out in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/hairboat/status/948714584214454272) by [hairboat ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/hairboat):

> Winter Bash wrap-up stats coming Soon™. I caught a cold in Florida and am currently channeling an icon:

Comment: It’s written and Rachel F. says I can post it tomorrow! \o/

Comment: Umm.. Who is Rachel.F?

Comment: The sister of Axel F.?

Comment: @NogShine Rachel is the (excellent) marketing manager who runs the blog. She’s the one who keeps people like me from letting our cats walk across our keyboards and publishing it on the blog as performance art.

Comment: @NogShine You mean RA Ch. Elf - the Retired Artistic Christmas Elf.

Comment: @hairboat What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Catija Nothing in theory. Thing is our cats all unionized and they demand unreasonable compensation for their art. I support the arts as much as anybody but even I’m unwilling to shell out 10 cans of salmon for “sssskskkkkkkkkkkkk4kk4444444444444”.

Comment: @hairboat Of course your cats are unionised. Can you imagine an ionised cat?

Comment: I wish images were more organised in the blog like previous years.

Comment: @AnkitSharma can you be a bit more specific? I want to hear more about this feedback so we can improve!

Comment: @RachelFerrigno my issue was all the images in start look bit messy as they were very different in size.